# Django (DRF) - get_queryset - Trying to return "images" with model "Product" as an extra field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a queryset which returns all Products. Every Product has one or more ProductImages and I want to add them as an extra field "images" for every product.

So the response I'm after is like `[ { id: 1, name: "prod1", images: images } ]`

I've tried the following implementations:

Models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My idea implemented in the simplest way

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        product_list = []

        # iterate over all products
        for product in queryset:
            images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=q.id)
            product['images'] = images
            product_list.append(product)

        return product_list
```

gives error

```
"TypeError: 'Product' object does not support item assignment"
```

New idea, make a new dict and add elements of product and add "images" as an extra field.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        product_list = []

        # iterate over all products
        for q in queryset:
            images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=q.id)
            product = {"id": q.id, "name": q.name, "description": q.description, "price": q.price, "images": images}
            product_list.append(product)

        return product_list
```

gives error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/product/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 687, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 538, in get_attribute
    relationship = get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 95, in get_attribute
    instance = instance[attr]
KeyError: 'categories'
```

I've been messing around with this for a while, could anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Here is an idea. Add another field to the `class Product` which is a `JSONField` called  `extra`. Then, use `product.extra = {'images': images}` in the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: @YusufErtas Thanks! This works, is this something that's commonly used? Also, why not call the field "images" instead of "extra"?

Comment: In general in DRF development when you want to dump certain attributes in a model without cluttering the field, this is pretty common actually. You are already using `images` as a key in the JSONField so I figured no need to use it twice. Also, you may also place other attributes in this field so it is common to call this field `extra`.

Comment: @YusufErtas Alright thank you. I'm still stuck with an issue, when I add images to extra it says "TypeError: Object of type ProductImage is not JSON serializable". How do I get around this?

Comment: Instead of appending the images directly, you can provide the url instead which is a string and hence JSON serializable:
`product.extra = {'images': [image.image.url for image in images]}`

Comment: Ah okay I figured, I was hoping there was a way to add the complete objects. Also, you can post your answer if you'd like.

Comment: I will post my latest comment as an answer. JSON Serializable objects are restricted to strings, arrays, etc. You could also try the byte representation of the image in the serializer but complete objects such as the picture itself would not be supported.

Comment: @YusufErtas I'm not looking to add the byte representation of the image. I'm only saving the path. I was just wondering how to add the complete model (id, name, other fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another field to the `class Product` which is a `JSONField` called `extra`. Then, use `product.extra = {'images': [image.image.url for image in images]}` in the get_queryset() method.